Am I using the Zener Diode Correctly?
I am building a custom atmeta328 board that I want to make sure handles the bootloader properly. I have DTR from my FTDI chip going through a .1uF capacitor to the Reset pin on the MCU.  I also have it pulled up to 5V via a 10K resistor. When I wire this up on a breadboard (using a 3.3V MCU that I had) I get the reset behavior I am looking for, however, when the DTR line goes back high there is a short voltage spike above 5V (3.3V in the screenshot) that I want to prevent. My understanding is that a zener diode with a 5V limit will cap that spike.
Here is what I am seeing using my DLA.

The top trace is what will feed into the MCU reset line.  The 2nd trace is what the GPIO (DTR) signal is at and the 3rd is the analog trace where I can see the spike when the DTR signal goes back high.  It is this spike I want to prevent.
Here is my schematic to do this.

I'm using this sot-23 zener diode just to keep everything surface mount on my board.
Question.  Do I have this correct and is the diode oriented properly?
Thank you :-)

Not really correctly, in addition to to what other answer say about the component pins being allocated incorrectly.
The first question is, why even have a zener there, what problem it will solve.
There are thousands of Arduinos made without this zener and they have not broken yet, at least because of the reset pin having 10V pulses.
In the ATMega328P data sheet, the absolute maximum rating for the RESET pin is 13V, and nominal range for using it during parallel programming must be within range of 11.5V and 12.5V anyway.
So the zener is not needed, as with 5V supply voltage and DTR pulling to 0V for a long time, the capacitor charges to 5V, and so when DTR rises to 5V, the reset does not have more than 10V anyway.
The zener is a 5.1V zener, but it means, it will have 4.84V to 5.36V when 20mA current flows through it.
With 10k pull-up resistor, the max current will be 0.5mA. Looking at the typical datasheet curve, the RESET pin voltage will be about 4.5V.
It might be too low and below the Brown-Out Detector Reset threshold if you use it.
Also elsewhere in the datasheet there is a requirement of RESET voltage being highe than 0.9*Vcc, or over 4.5V with 5V supply.
So if you want to add a zener, at least this 5.1V should not be used.
You might consider a diode or schottky diode to VCC instead, or higher voltage zener, if you want to clamp the voltage to not go much above VCC.
But the voltage going to 10V is not a problem that needs solving, so cheapest option is to just remove the zener and not put any component to limit the voltage.

Thanks, basically answered my question that this spike will not be an issue for the atmega328. I'll just remove it.  Thanks @Justme

No, your schematic model is wrong. It’s only a single Zener between 3-1 and your symbol is reversed.

Picture source: ONsemi datasheet (https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mmbz5221blt1-d.pdf)
